# Active Contest Ending 12 November 2018: Questions from CodeChef November Challenge

Tags: discussion, contests

Questions have begun arising on this site from an active contest.  It is the CodeChef November Challenge, which ends at 15:00 Indian Standard Time on 12 November 2018.  There are two divisions, depending on the ranking of the user.

Division 1 Questions:  https://www.codechef.com/NOV18A?order=desc&sortBy=successful_submissions

Division 2 Questions:  https://www.codechef.com/NOV18B?order=desc&sortBy=successful_submissions

I am posting this so that you are aware of this contest and can notify the moderators should one or more of these questions arise on this site.

For instance, here are two such questions:

[Number of subsequence of length k](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2986879/number-of-subsequence-of-length-k)

[Medians which lie in sequence of even length.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2986089/medians-which-lie-in-sequence-of-even-length)

Comment: Another example: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2983055/18398

Comment: Some more: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2983003/18398 and https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2985364/18398

Comment: We got swarms of CodeChef questions in October. Anybody know why this contest is attracting so many cheaters? They giving the winners free yachts or something?