# Active Contest Ending 18 December 2018: Questions from CodeChef December Challenge

Tags: discussion, contests

The [CodeChef December Challenge](https://www.codechef.com/DEC18) runs from 1500 Indian standard time 7 December 2018 until 1500 Indian standard time 17 December 2018.  In [past months](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29346/active-contest-ending-12-november-2018-questions-from-codechef-november-challen), this site has attracted numerous users who attempted to cheat on the contest problems.  There are two divisions of problems:

[Division 1](https://www.codechef.com/DEC18A?order=desc&sortBy=successful_submissions) for higher-ranked participants

[Division 2](https://www.codechef.com/DEC18B?order=desc&sortBy=successful_submissions) for lower-ranked participants

Should you spot a question from the contest, please vote to close it and notify the moderators that the question is from the contest so that they can close it for the duration of the contest, per site policy.

**Update:**  It was announced on 17 December 2018 that the contest has been extended for ten hours, so the contest appears to have been extended until 0100 Indian Standard Time on 18 December 2018.

Comment: I certainly appreciate you keeping on top of this particular contest.  Is it typically a monthly challenge, lasting roughly 10 days per month, from start to deadline?

Comment: @amWhy It seems that way.  I became aware of this contest since I have encountered attempts to cheat in past months while reading combinatorics questions.

Comment: Thanks for your keen eyes!